# Unhandled SqlException build issue

Tags: sqlexception

the issue I encoutered developing a simple web app that retrieves and displays data from a distant database has similar posts about it, but not quite the same, I went through them and I no solution actually helped me, so the issue is the following, when I debug my page, I wait a while and I'm redirected back to my project on Visual Studio with a Dialog Box entitled **SqlException was unhandled by user code**
the message in it reads:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Une connexion a été établie avec le serveur, mais une erreur s'est ensuite produite pendant la négociation préalable à l'ouverture de session. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l’hôte distant.)

---

The general trouble shooting tips didn't help, here is my aspx code:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Mail.aspx.cs" Inherits="CCIT_WebApp1.Mail" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="height: 470px">

<table runat="server">
    
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <tr class="Header">
            <td>Code</td>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("code") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

---

and this is my backend aspx.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApp1
{
    public partial class Mail : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (SqlConnection cnct = new SqlConnection("Server=x;User"+
               "ID=xx;Password=xxxx;Database=xxxx"))
            {

                cnct.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Code "+
                 "FROM Societe", cnct))
                {

                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        string code = rdr.GetString(1);

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Original**
This is likely your problem:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Code"+
                 "FROM Societe", cnct))
```

You need a space between Code and FROM. Should be: `SELECT Code From Societe`

**Second Try**

I would suggest wrapping your execution of the data reader in a try/catch block. Debug what's happening on the exception to see if it gives you any more meaningful information. Something like this...

`

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Code From Societe", sqlConn))
    {  
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlConn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dap.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          **Do something here **
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: there is a space there, I am just new to formattin gon stack overflow and I missremoved the space, I'll edit it, otherwise, the problem is still persistant

Comment: but now other errors come out, at least that's a start

Answer (score 0):

In same cases I test previously SQL query.
Suggest you to run query SELECT Code From Societe on database, to handle orriginal error.
Probobly table or column name typed with mistake, or something same